# Reschedule Sitecore Certification Exam after time has passed

Tags: certificate, training-certification

I was not able to start the Sitecore Certification exam on time due to some reason, and time has passed.

Now, I want to reschedule the Sitecore Certification Exam. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do it -

1. Email to Global Sitecore Training `globaltraining@sitecore.com`
2. Open a Sitecore Support Ticket on `Learning@Sitecore Support Case`. For this follow - https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1000647
3. Chat online on `Webassessor` chat support.

Comment: Not happy with the overall experience with Sitecore support for the above issue, they shared a discount coupon (I guess 25%) and asked me to purchase it again. Thank you for sharing this information, they have multiple email IDs in multiple locations which are deprecated but this will help the developer community.